# Automatically sync new Wordpress registrant to CiviCRM Contact

Tags: wordpress, contacts, user

We are in the process of switching a database of several thousand contacts to CiviCRM. We have a legacy Wordpress site, so we have CiviCRM nicely integrated in. We are about to go live. We don't want to force ALL our existing contacts to become Wordpress users, but as they renew memberships, give donations, sign up for events, we want to give them the option to register as a Wordpress user (Subscriber - we currently have 0 Wordpress Subscribers and a handful of WP Administrators). We are only requiring email and password to register. How do I get the new registrant to automatically either (1) become a new contact if the email is not in the CiviCRM contacts or; (2) simply assign the login to the right CiviCRM contact when the email matches? We can register new Wordpress users and run "Synchronize Users to Contacts" which works as desired, but we don't want to run the manual step. When they register the first time on Wordpress, we want the Contact relationship established immediately, so that they will be logged in and then can do the kinds of things we want our CiviCRM members and donors to do online.

Thanks for any help - we're pretty new at CiviCRM, really like it, but are still coming up to speed.

Comment: Here's a partial answer. Looking at some other related posts, I installed plugin CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync. Since I don't want to do a full sync and only want to go from Wordpress Subscriber --> CiviCRM Contact (no membership), I set the Settings on that plugin to only "Synchronize whenever a user logs in or logs out. This action is performed only on the user logging in or out." Exactly as we wanted. This worked. Only issue is it doesn't return to the page normally. See next comment.

Comment: Error Message: Warning: Missing argument 2 for Civi_WP_Member_Sync_Members::sync_to_user() in /home/karrud1/sdbikecoalition/wp-content/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/civi-wp-ms-members.php on line 352

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/karrud1/sdbikecoalition/wp-content/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/civi-wp-ms-members.php:352) in /home/karrud1/sdbikecoalition/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1174

Comment: One other piece to the puzzle. To register a new user on the page I installed the plugin "WP Register Profile With Shortcode" and to display a login dialog on the page (once registered), I installed the plugin "Login Widget With Shortcode." Perhaps a better plugin that handles the Login/Register/Lost Password dialog would ease the pain.

Comment: Karl: IIRC, we discussed the error and came to the conclusion that one of your login form plugins was incorrectly calling a WordPress hook with too few parameters.

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM does this by default. Every time a new user signs up for a Wordpress account on your site it will create a CiviCRM contact record automatically.